# How do I prevent backbone remove() from removing "el" in a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want remove a view before creating a new one. But my requirement is `view.remove()` should remove the view but not delete the `el` element. Having said this, I do not want to set `tagName` as it creates a new element which is unnecessary. Is there any way to remove a view from the memory leaving the `el` content cleared?

Comment: What happens if you use this.$el.html("")

Comment: I want to remove existing view instance before creating a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override Backbone's view `remove` method from within your abstract view:

```
remove: function() {
  // this._removeElement();
  this.$el.empty();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

Default source code: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-158

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this before with a disposable launcher view.

make sure your html contains a (class or id) anchor for your disposable view:
`<div class="content-container"></div>`

then make a LauncherView:

```
var LauncherView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },

    // inner views will be bound to ".launcher-container" via
    // their .el property passed into the options hash.
    template: _.template('<div class="launcher-container"></div>')
});
```

then instantiate your disposable launcher view:

`app.currentLauncherView = new LauncherView({});`

and append it to your DOM anchor:
`$('.content-container').append(app.currentLauncherView.el);`

then you can instantiate a view that will attach to the disposable launcher view:
`app.throwAway1 = new DisposableView({el: '.launcher-container'});`

And then when you want to destroy that view, you can do so with:

```
app.throwAway1.off();
app.throwAway1.remove();
app.currentLauncherView.remove();
```

Then you can put up a new view by instantiating a new LauncherView, attaching it to the DOM, and making your next view appear by binding it to '.launcher-container' .

```
app.currentLauncherView = new LauncherView({});
$('.content-container').append(app.currentLauncherView.el);
app.throwAway2 = new DisposableView({el: '.launcher-container'});
```